# How to break an object into chunks based on some property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
public class InvestorMailing
{
    public string To { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Attachments { get; set; }

    public int AttachmentCount { get; set; }

    public long AttachmentSize { get; set; }
}
```

i have an `IList<InvestorMailing> mailingList`.  if the attachment size is greater than x, then i need to split my object into chunks.  is there an easy linq-y way to do this?

Edited:

this is how i'm generating my mailings:

```
        var groupedMailings = mailingList.GroupBy(g => g.GroupBy);

        var investorMailings = groupedMailings.Select(
            g => new DistinctInvestorMailing
            {
                Id = g.Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                To = g.Key.Trim(),
                From = g.Select(x => x.From).FirstOrDefault(),
                FromName = g.Select(x => x.FromName).FirstOrDefault(),
                Bcc = g.Select(x => x.Bcc).FirstOrDefault(),
                DeliveryCode = g.Select(x => x.DeliveryCode).FirstOrDefault(),
                Subject = g.Select(x => x.Subject).FirstOrDefault(),
                Body = g.Select(x => x.Body).FirstOrDefault(),
                CommentsOnStatus = g.Select(x => x.CommentsOnStatus).FirstOrDefault(),
                Attachments = g.Select(x => x.AttachmentPath),
                AttachmentCount = g.Select(x => x.AttachmentPath).Count(),
                AttachmentSize = g.Sum(x => x.AttachmentSize),
                MailType = g.Select(x => x.MessageType).FirstOrDefault()
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you want to split? The list  of InvestorMailings or the Attachments of an individual InvestorMailing?

Comment: InventorMailing is an object and each has its own AttachmentCount property. When do you want to split? Do you want to split even if a single item in the list is greater than x?

Comment: Nearly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678008/how-to-split-linq-grouping

Comment: i want to split the single InvestorMailing if the attachment size is greater than x.  for example, maxAttachmentSize is 10mb.  so if an InvestorMailing AttachmentSize is 30mb, i want 3 InvestorMailings.

Comment: @CurlyFro: What's the difference between an `InvestorMailing` and a `DistrictInvestorMailing`?

Comment: InvestorMailing mailingList is a flat list where To has dups and the AttachmentPath is unique per To.

DistrictInvestorMailing groups the Tos where each unique To has multiple attachments (ie AttachmentPaths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty simple to do it with a standard method. Consider this example:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int weight) { Weight = weight; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
IEnumerable<IList<Foo>> GroupFoosByWeight(IList<Foo> foos, int weightLimit)
{
    List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
    int sumOfWeight = 0;

    foreach (Foo foo in foos)
    {
        if (sumOfWeight + foo.Weight > weightLimit)
        {
            yield return list;
            sumOfWeight = 0;
            list.Clear();
        }

        list.Add(foo);
        sumOfWeight += foo.Weight;
    }

    if (list.Count > 0)
        yield return list;
}
```

...

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo(15), new Foo(32), new Foo(14), new Foo(19), new Foo(27)
};

foreach (IList<Foo> list in GroupFoosByWeight(foos, 35))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", list.Count, list.Sum(f => f.Weight));
}
```

**Edit**

I worked on it a bit and produced a LINQ version. It doesn't really save much code in this case, but it's a start.

```
int weightLimit = 35;
int fooGroup = 0;
int totalWeight = 0;

Func<Foo, int> groupIncrementer = f =>
{
    if (totalWeight + f.Weight > weightLimit)
    {
        fooGroup++;
        totalWeight = 0;
    }

    totalWeight += f.Weight;

    return fooGroup;
};

var query = from foo in foos
            group foo by new { Group = groupIncrementer(foo) }
                into g
                select g.AsEnumerable();

foreach (IList<Foo> list in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", list.Count, list.Sum(f => f.Weight));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using some LINQ to find a chunk that has enough space left to add the attachment:

```
var chunks = new List<List<InvestorMailing>>();
int maxAttachmentsSize = 10;

foreach (InvestorMailing mail in mailingList)
{
    var chunkWithSpace = chunks
        .Where(list => list.Sum(x => x.AttachmentSize) +
                       mail.AttachmentSize <= maxAttachmentsSize)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (chunkWithSpace != null)
    {
        chunkWithSpace.Add(mail);
    } else {
        chunks.Add(new List<InvestorMailing> { mail });
    }
}
```

The result is stored in `chunks`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
var highs = mailingList.Where(i => i.AttachmentSize > 10000).ToList();
var lows = mailingList.Where(i => i.AttachmentSize <= 10000).ToList();
```

How do you need to break them apart aside from this?

HTH.

Comment: I *think* he wants to process these things in batches. So once he exceeds some given threshold, perform an action and continue. So it's not really the individual size, but the collective.